# Internet Explorer 7 Ajax not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I'm using ajax to load a list of users to display in a table.  For some reason in IE7 the list will not load?  Not quite for sure what the problem is and troubleshooting older versions I've always found challenging.

Here is the link:  http://blooming-ice-7964.herokuapp.com/

Works in everything but IE7.  This is RoR application so the CSS/JS is minimized.

Here is the method I call on the initial load of the page to get the json results:

```
inout.replaceUsers = function() {
  var $body = $('#user-list').find('tbody');
  $.getJSON('/', function(data) {
    $body.empty();
    $body.html($('#user-list-template').render(data));
    inout.refresh();
  });
};
```

Here is the jQuery on the main page that calls the method above:

```
$(function() {
    inout.replaceUsers();
  });
```

I'm using jsRender with a template for all of this to render out.

Comment: Tried it with IE8 in IE7 mode and it worked

Comment: Yea, but with IE7 it doesn't.  Use IE tester or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `callback=?` to the querystring.

```
inout.replaceUsers = function() {
  var $body = $('#user-list').find('tbody');
  $.getJSON('/?callback=?', function(data) {
    $body.empty();
    $body.html($('#user-list-template').render(data));
    inout.refresh();
  });
};
```

Comment: why? I don't see anything about JSONP

Comment: @JuanMendes, IE7 will fail without it.

Comment: This sort of worked for me.  I had to use '/?callback=' without the question mark.  Otherwise rails seemed to not like the route.